# Как заполнить поля формы данными из массива?

Tags: javascript, массивы, dom

Есть форма и массив. Как сделать, чтобы по щелчку по кнопке заполнилась форма соответственно ключам?

```js
var contacts =
[
 {
  name: 'Ivan',
  surname: 'Ivanov',
  phone: 123123123
 }
];
```

```css
#customerId
{
 width: 200px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<title>Задание 2</title>
<form name="customer" id="customerId">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for = 'name'>Ваше имя</label>
  <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" name="customerName" placeholder="введите имя" rule-required/>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for = 'lastname'>Ваша Фамилия </label>
  <input class="form-control" id="lastname" type="text" placeholder=" введите фамилию" rule-required/>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for = 'number'>Номер телефона</label>
  <input class="form-control" id="number" type="text" placeholder="введите номер"/>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control" id="code" type="text" hidden placeholder="code"/>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <button type="button" onclick="getAdd(this.form)" class="btn btn-default" id="btn">Добавить</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: из псевдомассива contacts чтоли?

Comment: Да, из него. Чтобы получилось в форме 
Ivan
Ivanov
123123123

Comment: Анна Тот написала ниже в своём отклике: «А если в массиве будет больше элементов? Например: var contacts = [ { name: 'Ivan', surname: 'Ivanov', phone: 123123123 }, { name: 'Iva545n', surname: 'Iva5677nov', phone: 23123 }, { name: 'Tya545n', surname: 'Grt7nov', phone: 2343423 } ] »

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно отправлять данные на сервер, то нужно добавить атрибуты  `name="customerSurname"` и `name="customerPhone"` для 2-ого и 3-его `input`. Я их добавил ниже. Иначе сервер не получит данных из них. Атрибут `name="customerName"` у вас уже был для первого поля.

Используя эти атрибуты мы можем напрямую через объект формы обращаться к `input`-объектам, к примеру так: `form.customerName`. При этом нам не нужно выискивать их через `document.getElementById` и поэтому id для `input`-ов излишни.

Также у вас не хватает закрывающего тега к форме: `</form>`.

Ещё у вас ошибка в том, что вы написали `type="text" hidden`, а надо `type="hidden`", поскольку `hidden` - это значение атрибута, а не атрибут.

В общем, я сделал так, как вы пожелали в своём комментарии здесь - т. е. при нажатии на кнопку выбирается следующий объект с данными и ими заполняется форма. Если данные заканчиваются, то начинаем сначала, и так по кругу.

```js
var index = 0;

var contacts =
[
 {
  name: 'Ivan',
  surname: 'Ivanov',
  phone: 123123123
 },
 {
  name: 'Вася',
  surname: 'Васильев',
  phone: 312231231
 },
 {
  name: 'Iva545n',
  surname: 'Iva5677nov',
  phone: 23123
 },
 {
  name: 'Tya545n',
  surname: 'Grt7nov',
  phone: 2343423
 }
];


function getAdd(form)
{
 //ставим index в начало, если список закончился
 if(index > contacts.length - 1)
  index = 0;

 form.customerName.value = contacts[index].name;
 form.customerSurname.value = contacts[index].surname;
 form.customerPhone.value = contacts[index].phone;

 index++;
}
```

```css
#customerId
{
 width: 200px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>Задание 2</title>
<form name="customer" id="customerId">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for = 'name'>Ваше имя</label>
  <input class="form-control" id="name" name="customerName" type="text" placeholder="введите имя" rule-required/>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for = 'lastname'>Ваша Фамилия </label>
  <input class="form-control" id="lastname" name="customerSurname" type="text" placeholder=" введите фамилию" rule-required/>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for = 'number'>Номер телефона</label>
  <input class="form-control" id="number" name="customerPhone" type="text" placeholder="введите номер"/>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control" id="code" type="hidden" placeholder="code"/>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <button type="button" onclick="getAdd(this.form)" class="btn btn-default" id="btn">Добавить</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var contacts = [{
  name: 'Ivan',
  surname: 'Ivanov',
  phone: 123123123
}];

function getAdd() {
  document.getElementById('name').value = contacts[0].name;
  document.getElementById('lastname').value = contacts[0].surname;
  document.getElementById('number').value = contacts[0].phone;
}
```

```css
#customerId {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form name="customer" id="customerId">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for='name'>Ваше имя</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" name="customerName" placeholder="введите имя" rule-required/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for='lastname'>Ваша Фамилия </label>
    <input class="form-control" id="lastname" type="text" placeholder=" введите фамилию" rule-required/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for='number'>Номер телефона</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="number" type="text" placeholder="введите номер" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" id="code" type="text" hidden placeholder="code" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="button" onclick="getAdd()" class="btn btn-default" id="btn">Добавить</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: А если в массиве будет больше элементов?
Например:
var contacts = [
  {
    name: 'Ivan',
    surname: 'Ivanov',
    phone: 123123123
  },
  {
    name: 'Iva545n',
    surname: 'Iva5677nov',
    phone: 23123
  },
  {
    name: 'Tya545n',
    surname: 'Grt7nov',
    phone: 2343423
  }
]

Comment: Так ведь форма у вас одна. Или будет больше кнопок? Как понять какие конкретно данные заполнять? Уточните пожалуйста вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, добавьте input'ам dataset (например, data-key="name") с соответствующими ключам из вашего объекта названиям, потом соберите их в массив:

var elems = document.querySelectorAll('*[data-key]');

И при переборе Вашего объекта, просто передавайте значения из него в input'ы. Пример кода:

```
    var contacts = [{
        name: 'Ivan',
        surname: 'Ivanov',
        phone: 123123123
    }];

    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('*[data-key]');

    for (let index = 0; index < elems.length; index++) {
        // значение из dataset
        var val = elems[index].dataset.key;
        // проверка наличия данного ключа в вашем объекте
        if (val in contacts[0]) {
            // передача значения в input
            elems[index].value = contacts[0][val];
        }
    }
```

Всё это можно положить в функцию и саму функцию передавать при нажатии на кнопку. Например:

var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', yourFn);